# JQuery Manipulate serialized/deserialized Element before display/after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have an existing AJAX webpage. The code is straightforward Javascript: call an URL ($.Ajax() , receive html from a PHP backend (.done(function(data) {...}), display it using $("#Content").html(data). There is also a "Submit" button, the sender script uses form.serialize() to read the form into a JSON string and $.ajax() to send it to the backend.

Is there any technique I can use to hook into the display/serialization process and do conversions on the fly, i.e. change values before they get displayed, and change values before they get serialized in such a way that they won't appear on screen?

### Long story

the backend will always send datetime values as form inputs with the value set in UTC and YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format. On the client side I need datetime values in some local format and timezone, depending on the browser settings. After a while of experimenting with datetime-local and giving up on it because of countless cissues with diffrerent browsers I decided to submit the form input as type="text" and do the conversion work myself.

I have a working solution to convert the values using the moment.js library, but since the code comes after the .html(data) statement, after loading the form the UTC values become visible for some time, before they "magically" change. The same problem occurs in reverse when submitting the form, when I need to convert the local values back to the format the portal expects.

While my solution technically works, I'd like to optimize the process so the conversion is integrated into the display/serialization process.

Comment: you can modify the data object **before** you append it to the page using `html()`

Comment: the same can be done with the input for the ajax

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. What you suggest is exactly what I am doing right now. data (see code decription above) is a string, and right now I search for html tags / ?parameter tokens and replace values using string manipulation commands. While it works, it's not very oop like.